# Concept help: Cylinder is a regular surface

Tags: differential-geometry

> Show that the cylinder $\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2=1\}$ is a regular surface, and find parameterizations whose coordinate neighborhoods cover it.

How can I find the parameterization $\mathbf{x}: U\rightarrow V\cap S$? I am aware of all of the criteria: differentiability, homeomorphism, and for each $q\in U,d\mathbf{x}_q :\Bbb{R}^2\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^3$ is one-to-one. But how can I go about "guessing" a good parameterization? And how can I find $U$? I am not really interested in the actual answer--I just want to know how to begin problems like these. What kind of strategies do we use for regular surface problems?

My idea was this: Since $U$ must be an open set, let $U=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2<1\}$. Then choose $\mathbf{x}(u,v)=(u,v,c)$ where $c\in\Bbb{R}$ is the height of the cylinder. Not sure if this is the right way to start.